# I want to move to the left edge of the cell, the image

Tags: ios, uitableview

I was displaying an image on `UITableviewcell`.
I'm getting in the URL image.
I'm getting asynchronously image.
There is a blank space on the left side of the image.
I want to remove the margin on the left side of the image.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the blank space part of the image? Else try with the `UIImageView` `contentMode`, or `UIEdgeInset`.

Comment: You probably need to create a custom UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of **UITableView** . Try like this

`if ([table respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [table setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }`

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**
Create a custom UITableViewCell

**step 2**
place the image View on one edge

**step 3**
since the picture is coming asynchronously, there may be a problem of getting actual image size. to avoid this prob.
scale the image in the size you want it to be.
using this snippet

```
 -(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
                  scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if space is not part of image..

```
 UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
 img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
 [cell addSubview:img];
```